# How to make a row in color with activeadmin based on if else condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I'm using Active Admin for my application. I want to color a row if the condition is true and some other color is condition is false.

```
tr.odd, tr.even {
    &.test {
        td.col {
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to apply this condition for test class. Is there any way possible to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to have two different CSS classes and then apply the different classes in your ERB views for instance like this:

```
<tr class="<%= condition ? 'test' : 'default' %>">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

Ideally you would move this to a helper like this

```
# application_helper.rb
def css_class_for(condition)
  if condition
    'test-css-class'
  else
    'other-css-class'
  end
end

# view
<tr class="<%= css_class_for(true) %>">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr
```